Function not being mocked unless full path is called
main.py
from path.to.mod import run

def foo(args: str):
    run(args)

test.py
@patch("path.to.mod.run")
def verify_args(mock):
    foo("bar")
    mock.assert_called_once_with("bar")

the above code does not mock run ie assertion fails.
However if I change main.py to
def foo(args: str):
    path.to.mod.run(args)

then the test mocks successfully
How can I mock without needing specify full path from main.py?
if I change test.py to
from path.to.mod import run
@patch("run")
def verify_args(mock):
    foo("bar")
    mock.assert_called_once_with("bar")

it complains that run is not a valid target
TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'run'


https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

thanks @jonrsharpe!
Patching main.run (instead of path.to.mod.run) worked as per the doc you shared

If anyone else is having the same problem/confusion,
the documentation says:

The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.

So in test.py I had to mock main.run (where it is looked up) and not path.to.mod.run (where it is defined).
